# Intellisense for member override in VB.Net 2008 Express Edition

Tags: vb.net, intellisense, overriding

If I override a member (e.g AutoSize in the Button Class), then the intellisense no longer appears in the editor, forcing me to re-decorate the property.

Is there an option somewhere that I need to check?

ETA: Here's a code sample:

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Overrides Property AutoSize() As Boolean
        Get
            Return MyBase.AutoSize
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.AutoSize = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

If I then type:

```
Dim b as New MyButton
b.AutoSize ...
```

The intellisense explaining the AutoSize property doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a property is visible in IntelliSense is controlled by the [EditorBrowsable] attribute.  VB.NET is a bit special because it hides EditorBrowsableState.Advanced by default.

None of this would apply to an override to Button.AutoSize, it is always visible.  Maybe you can give a better example, a code snippet is *always* good.

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about the comment "Gets or sets a value ...".  Yes, that doesn't get 'inherited'.  That wouldn't be appropriate, you overrode it with (normally) the specific intention to alter its behavior.  Same in C#.  You need to add XML documentation to fix that.